# Ace Editor API: How to select line 2?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to select line 2 for copy & paste in ACE. There is a method `selectLine()`, which is documented here: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=selection but i don't understand how to use it. Unfortunately its also nothing to find on stackoverflow.com about selection, only about highlighting, which is not the same.

```
// ACE Editor Setup
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/crimson_editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.setValue("textline1\n textline2\n textline3");

var select = new Selection(editor.getSession());    // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
select.selectLine(2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once ace is initialized, it creates a `Selection` object instance therefore you don't need to recreate it. To access `Selection` just use `editor.selection`.

Another important point is `selectLine` selects the current line (it doesn't accept any parameters). So to move the cursor and select the line you have to first use `moveCursorToPosition` function.

Here is an example:

```
editor.selection.moveCursorToPosition({row: 1, column: 0});
editor.selection.selectLine();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks that helps. What i really want to do is: always select the current line, when cursor changes. and remove that line with a keypress. i know how to add keybord commands. But i don't know how to do something `onCursorChange()`, it seems to be different from `Editor.on("change", function(Object e))`. and also i don't find how remove the selected line.

Comment: i have also tried something like `editor.onCursorChange(editor.selection.selectLine());`, but i guess something like this can not consume events. it even not works.

Comment: i have posted a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455842/ace-editor-api-how-to-select-current-line-oncursorchange-and-remove-it-on-keyst

Comment: @Lutz If this has helped please select it as an answer